# Roblox: Spawn and Teams

Tags: lua, roblox

I am new to Roblox, guess that would make me a Noob. I am not trying to be a "Developer" I just enjoy fun techy stuff because it helps me relax.

In my game, I am trying to accomplish something very simple (I assume). I have five spawners for players, and one for Admins (me), respectively colored Gold and Mid Gray (because I couldn't find silver).

I have followed instructions in videos and websites alike and I can't seem to resolve what I would assume is a minor issue.

What I have done:

My spawn location:

Name: Admin
AllowTeamChangeOn: Disabled
Neutral: Disabled
Team Color: Gold

In the folder, ServerScriptStorage, I have the following script that I found on a youtube video.

```lua
local t = game.Teams.Admins

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)

if plr.name == "MrEdgarHallow" then

  plr.Team = t

end)
```

in my team's folder, I have teams established for Admins and Players alike

Admin:

AutoAssignable: Disabled
Name: Admins
TeamColor: Gold

Players:

AutoAssignable: Disabled
Name: Players
TeamColor: Mid Gray

Obviously, I am doing something wrong, because it won't work.

I was able to successfully achieve my goal with a team name and color of "White", though that was not my intention so I wanted to change it.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about roblox, and the API / table contents defined in there, but regarding the Lua snippet you posted there is one `end` statement missing (to end function definition):

```
local t = game.Teams.Admins
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    if plr.name == "MrEdgarHallow" then 
        plr.Team = t
    end
end )
```

If this was not the root cause of the problem, then please check if you can get any log to give more details on the issue than "it won't work."